# How to stop form submission on hubspot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hubspot

I have form from which if you enter company name and the validation is correct then it will redirect to the company page but if misspelled company name or company name is not available then it shows error. now the validation is working fine but the form submission in not stopping and it show me thank you message.

I tried `return false` & also `e.preventDefault();` but none of them are working. The form submits data through ajax.

**here is the JS code**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var gett;
    var op_value = [];
    var op_urls = [];
    var op_spell = [];
    $(".hs_company input").keyup(function() {
        gett = $(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '');
        $('.sidebar-form input[type=hidden]').val(gett).change();
    });

    $(".sidebar-form form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.hs_company_list option').each(function() {
            op_spell.push($(this).text().substring(0, 3));
            op_value.push($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, ''));
            op_urls.push($(this).val());
        });
        var sliced_str = gett.substring(0, 3);
        if ($.inArray(gett, op_value) !== -1) {
            var op_data = $.inArray(gett, op_value);

            setInterval(function() {
                window.location.href = op_urls[op_data];
            }, 2000);
            return false;
        } else if ($.inArray(sliced_str, op_spell) > -1) {

            $(".sidebar-form .hs-button").before("<label>Misspelled Company Name<label>");

            return false;
        } else {

            $(".sidebar-form .hs-button").before("<label>Company Not Found<label>");

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: you have to write a condition for validation then reset and .preventDefault();

Comment: @MerajKhan I have added the validation in the code look the `if-else` conditions but how to reset the `.preventDefault()`??

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the submit event on the form after it has already been submitted. In your code `$(".sidebar-form form").submit(function(e)`  you're automatically submiting the form. You can use on submit or try to put a condition in your function. exs:

with condition:

```
$(".sidebar-form form").submit(function () {

    var form = $(".sidebar-form form");

    if (form.validate() === true) {
        $(this).submit(function () {
            return false;
        });
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

or with on submit :

```
$(".sidebar-form form").on("submit", "form", function() {
$(this).submit(function() {
    return false;
});
return true;
});
```

Comment: Hi Dev65, edited the answer with the jquery plug-in validate().

Comment: I just updated the code as you suggested but still no luck :(
for ex.`activenation` this the company name then this must not be incorrect

Comment: The validation plugin only check for default form validation like phone no., email etc